# Versionamento de pacotes NuGet ou versionamento do Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Para criar o projeto estou usando a metodologia CODE-FIRST, porem para fazer alguns testes no banco tive que fazer um *Seeding Service*  (populacionar o banco de dados diretamente do código ) para isso tive que fazer alguns ajustes, desde então não consigo mais criar um novo *controller*.

medidas ja realizadas:

- Voltei todas as configurações (( mas, não voltei no versionamento git)).
- Alterei as versões do Entity Framework.
- Alterei as versões dos pacotes do NuGet.
- Alterei as versões do banco de dados. 
  Nenhuma das alternativas acima solucionaram o problemas.

*mensagem de erro em anexo*.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Especificações:
Entity Framework: 2.1

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tente reinstalar o pacote: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design/

Comment: Obrigado Felipe!